# Command to generate /dev/disk/-by-path/ name on a system without udev daemon

Tags: devices, disk, block-device

On most Linux systems udev usually creates symlinks in

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/
/dev/disk/by-path/
```

which point to actual device nodes (`/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc).

I don't have udev on my system, and I would like to generate these symlinks manually. I know I can use `blkid` to generate the `by-uuid` name.

But how can I generate the `by-path` name for a given disk (e.g. `/dev/sda1`) without using udev?

Specifically, I am looking for a way to find which of my disks is the disk connected via iSCSI from host `10.1.14.22`. It could be `sdb`, or `sdc` or perhaps other, since I am connected to several (different) iSCSI hosts at the same time.

Comment: They are `/dev/disk/by-id`, `/dev/disk/by-path`, and `/dev/disk/by-uuid`. They are not `/dev/disk-by-uuid` and `/dev/disk-by-path`.

Comment: The source for generating the path id is in `src/udev/udev-builtin-path_id.c` in the source of `systemd`. You can translate it into shell script.

Comment: Do you have a working sysfs?  For me, `realpath /sys/block/sdd/device/scsi_device` gives a plausible-looking value of `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/host12/target12:0:0/12:0:0:0/scsi_device`, which looks like it needs only a little massaging to get the corresponding name (`/dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0` in this case).

Comment: So here's a question. Where do the UUIDs come from? I always assumed this was some identifying string embedded inside the drives themselves.

Comment: @Toby Speight - yes, I do have working /sys. But however I massage `realpath`, it does not show the IP address of the iISCSI host.

Comment: I don't have iSCSI - what link do you get in your sysfs paths?  (you might want to [edit] your question to add the extra info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script would do the trick, at least for most typical scenarios. It requires on `blkid`, `lsscsi` and `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /dev/disk/by-{path,uuid}
for dev in `blkid -o device | grep -v block`; do
  ln -s "$dev" "/dev/disk/by-uuid/$(blkid -o value -s UUID "$dev")"
done

lsscsi -v | sed 'N;s/\n//' |\
  sed 's/.*\(\/dev\/\w\+\).*\(pci\)[0-9]\{4\}[^/]\+\/[^/]\+\/\([0-9:.]\+\)[^ ]*\/\([0-9:]\+\)[]].*/\1 \2-\3-scsi-\4/' |\
  sed 's/.*\(\/dev\/\w\+\).*\(pci\)[^/]*\/\([0-9:.]\+\)\/ata[^ ]*\/\([0-9:]\+\)[]].*/\1 \2-\3-ata-\4/' |\
  while read dev pci; do
    pp="/dev/disk/by-path/$pci"
    ln -s "$dev" "$pp"
    for part in "${dev}"[0-9]*; do
      [ -e "$part" ] && ln -s "$part $pp-part${part/$dev/}"
    done
  done
```

Comment: @TobySpeight `blkid -o device` lists all `/dev/*` and `/dev/block/*` devices. `/dev/block/*` are likely produced by udev, so in Martin's system should not be a problem. Thanks for that, I'm updating the script with your solution which is more elegant.

Comment: My code tests that `blkid -s UUID` isn't empty - not all my block devices have UUIDs, and I didn't want to end up with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/sdd1` etc.  I also use `ln -r` to get results exactly like udev's, but I expect that isn't important.

Comment: My `blkid -o device` doesn't give me any `/dev/block/*` - not sure what's different there...